# How to authorize ssh key in Github via their API

Tags: python, api, github, python-requests, pygithub

My Github org requires SAML SSO authentication for all members, which requires new ssh keys added to an account to be authorized (https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/authorizing-an-ssh-key-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on). I've tried researching and looking thru their API docs, but I can't find anything about authorizing the ssh key via API.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to GitHub Support with this question on May 3, 2022 and received the following response:

> Currently it's not possible to authorize an accounts SSH keys or
> personal access token for SSO in any other way than through the web
> UI. However, we have an open internal feature request to allow SSO
> authorization to be controlled via the API. [...]
>
> We cannot say if or when any of these requests will be implemented.
> Keep an eye on the [GitHub Changelog](https://github.blog/changelog/) for information on when and if
> this makes it into the product.